# Ajax Jquery and php: How to control feedback?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, feedback

Let's suppose you're sending data through ajax. The server will process it (PHP) and sends a feedback that you can grab using `Complete: function(data) { //WRITE HTML TO DIV $('#somehing').html(data) }`
The question is: 
is there a way to modify data (edit, delete) before passing it to an html element?

Here's a simple example of what I mean :

```
//php side
echo 'Invalid email';
echo 'Enter your username';
echo 'fine';
echo 1;
echo 2;


// Jquery and Ajax
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: 'render.php',
data:values,
complete: function(data) {
$('#something').html(data) /* all those messages in php will be printed 
into #something including the numbers. how to delete or edit those numbers 
from appearing in #something? */
}
});
```

Comment: how are you receiving the response? is it an html markup? or json?

Comment: I recieve it as 'html'

Comment: If you're recieving it as `html`, then just wrap it, `if($(data).find('myElement').text().match('/[0-9]/'){ //numbers }`

Comment: how your server side script returns array? You are saying it is returning html

Comment: @RohanKumar `.indexOf()` is also a String method.

Comment: @RohanKumar my server side returns strings and numbers, those are stored in an array 'I named it: data' in complete:function(data) {//Some code}.

Comment: First try to check the type of object that javascript is receiving using typeof or just printing it with console.log()

But as a good practice I'd suggest to always return json from server side.

Comment: @fritsMaister, at first I thought 'data' was an array containing strings, and each string has an index. but in fact 'data' was a whole string, I tested it with typeof(). Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to remove the numbers like,

```
complete:function(data){
   data=data.replace(/\d+/,''); // Regular expression without quotation marks.
   // or you can replace the something text like
   // $('#something').text(function(){
   //     return this.innerText.replace(/\d+/,'');
   // });
   alert(data);
}
```

Comment: it works! without quotation marks around your regular expression : (/\d+/, ' '); Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Data is returned as basically just a string the way you say you are doing it "receive it as 'html'"  You should be able to use simple javascript to control it right out of the gate, for example the way I do things sometimes is this:

the PHP returns something like:

```
echo $variable_1 . ":" . $variable_2
```

Then when I get that as `data` it is just a string that says

```
variable 1:variable 2
```

So what I do next is I separate the variables by the colon

```
var var1 = data.split(":")[0];
var var2 = data.split(":")[1];
```

Now, this is just a simple example.  I'm not exactly sure what you're returning, but it seems that you're searching for an index of `1` instead of `"1"`.  This could make a difference.  Try searching for 1 in quotes, this would then be searching through a string.

Comment: Thank you ntgCleaner, In my case I have many strings : most of them are error messages (for example if a user puts an invalid email: it returns the string 'invalid email') However there are numbers (in php I echo them without quotes eg: echo 1;) I would like to use them for something else and I don't want them to appear with error messages. this is why I'm asking about a way to control the returned data.

Comment: yeah split :P I also do this thing even though it is immature :D